# usestate hooks combined with timers not working properly inside useeffect hook

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

Here I used usestate hook for **val**

my code is updating **val** correctly through an extra global variable **g**  when **setinterval** is calling **tick** function!!

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import { ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import { StyleSheet, View, FlatList, Alert, TouchableWithoutFeedback,TouchableOpacity, Keyboard,Text} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
import Slider from '@react-native-community/slider';
import * as Progress from 'react-native-progress';
export default function Status({route,navigation}) {
  let [val,setvalue]=useState(0);
  var g=0;
  useEffect(()=>{
    setTimeout(() => {
      navigation.navigate('Home',{xx:"hhh"});
    }, 5000);
   
  },[]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const x=setInterval(tick, 50);
     return ()=>{
            clearInterval(x);
     }
  },[])
  function tick()
  {
    console.log('hi');
    g=g+0.01;
    setvalue(g);
  }
  const {image,text}=route.params;
  return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <ImageBackground source={{uri:image}} imageStyle={styles.image} style={styles.border}>
          <Progress.Bar  progress={val} width={null} />
          <Text  style={styles.input}>{text}</Text>
        </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    },
    image: {
        flex:1,
        resizeMode: 'cover'
      },
      border: {
        flex:1,
        justifyContent:'flex-end'
      },
      input: {
        flex:1,
        height: 40,
        fontSize:20,
        padding:2,
        color:'white',
        //width:null,
        marginTop: 500,
        marginBottom:10,
        borderWidth: 0,
        borderColor:null,
        borderRadius:10,
        alignSelf:'center'
      }
});
```

but here my code is not updating **val** when **setinterval** is calling **tick** function??
please help!!

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import { ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import { StyleSheet, View, FlatList, Alert, TouchableWithoutFeedback,TouchableOpacity, Keyboard,Text} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
import Slider from '@react-native-community/slider';
import * as Progress from 'react-native-progress';
export default function Status({route,navigation}) {
  let [val,setvalue]=useState(0);
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    setTimeout(() => {
      navigation.navigate('Home',{xx:"hhh"});
    }, 5500);
   
  },[]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const x=setInterval(tick, 50);
     return ()=>{
            clearInterval(x);
     }
  },[])
  function tick()
  {
    console.log('hi');
    setvalue(val+0.01);
  }
  const {image,text}=route.params;
  return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <ImageBackground source={{uri:image}} imageStyle={styles.image} style={styles.border}>
          <Progress.Bar  progress={val} width={null} />
          <Text  style={styles.input}>{text}</Text>
        </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    },
    image: {
        flex:1,
        resizeMode: 'cover'
      },
      border: {
        flex:1,
        justifyContent:'flex-end'
      },
      input: {
        flex:1,
        height: 40,
        fontSize:20,
        padding:2,
        color:'white',
        //width:null,
        marginTop: 500,
        marginBottom:10,
        borderWidth: 0,
        borderColor:null,
        borderRadius:10,
        alignSelf:'center'
      }
});
```

Here I am using a progress bar and It should update progress automatically for 5 seconds and after I am navigating to another home screen.

I want to know why my second code is not working as expected as from the first code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**setvalue** is asynchronous function and because of this value is not set immediately after call. You try to update value based on current value in short range of time which cause the issue. You should use callback passed to **setvalue** which get you correct previous value event if state will not have time to update yet.

```
setvalue( prevValue => prevValue + 0.01 )
```